# fast parse property of flat file source

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am using the flat file source for a large data migration and the source data in the text stream form unlike UI, datetime or sting. The component is not supporting for fast parsing for text stream.

Could I get any ideas to improve fast performance in this scenario.

thanks
prav

Comment: What do you mean by "form unlike UI, datetime or sting"

Comment: My data type is text_stream and the FastParse property is not supporting to text_stream while it is supporting other than string formats.
thanks 
prav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen fast parse does not support strings. It only supports integers, date and time and then with [caveats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139833.aspx)

The first thing I would do is ensure that you're using the smallest data types you can in your flow definition (WSTR rather than NTEXT for example if you're strings < 4000 characters).

Answer (score 0):

This problem has solved by taking DT_STR instead of DT_TEXT by chaning my DB design for better performance issue. I got 1 million rows transfer in 13 sec. Which is required for my business logic.

thanks
prav